# Numpy not found in Python3

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run numpy in Python 3, using the WinPy distribution. I put #!python3 at the top of the script, because I was told that is something that Winpy has that allows you to make it run in a certain version. If I run the script in the shell(Eclipse) it works fine, but when I try to run it from the console, I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Dax\workspace\Python3\TestofPython3.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

If I don't put that at that the top of the script, it runs numpy fine until it gets to 'input()'. It works in the shell with or without #!python3.

Comment: have you tried `<pathtoyourpython>\scripts\pip install numpy` ?

Comment: Sounds like you have numpy installed for python 2, but not python 3.  Also, python 2 uses `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

The "#!python3" is to help the console determine the right version of python. However you need to make sure the path is correct. Instead of putting "#!python3", put "#!/usr/bin/" and then your python version, so "python" or "python3".

Check this article for more information on this. [Article on "#!" Scripts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)